# Minimum size of a minimal generating set of a finite abelian group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, abelian-groups, finitely-generated

I am trying to prove that the minimum size of a minimal generating set of a finite abelian group $G$, denoted $d(G)$, where $G=C_{d_{1}} \times \dots \times C_{d_{k}}$ for $d_{i} \mid d_{i+1}$, is $k$. Note that I am using minimal generating set to mean no redundant generators. I have proven so far that $k=\max\{d(P)\}$, where each $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ for each prime $p \mid G$.

1. To finish my proof of the main result, it suffices to show that $d(H) \leq d(G)$ for $H \leq G$. I know this does not hold for non-abelian groups, but I think it is true for abelian groups, although I am having a hard time proving it. Is this true, and if so could someone please point me to how I could prove this?
2. If this is not true, could someone please point me to how I could continue the proof that $d(G)=k$?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Prove a result on the size of the minimal set that generates a finite abelian group](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/657272/prove-a-result-on-the-size-of-the-minimal-set-that-generates-a-finite-abelian-gr)

Comment: @AnneBauval I've not really been able to make sense of that explanation although that is the same result I want to prove.

Answer (score 0):

I believe I have managed to work out the proof by showing that every Sylow $p$-subgroup of $G$ is isomorphic to a quotient of $G$. I then used the fact that $d(G/N) \leq d(G)$, which follows by definition. This showed that $d(G) \geq k$. I also showed that $d(G) \leq k$ by using the fact that $d(H \times K) \leq d(H)+d(K)$.